# How can I read every letter from the file?

Tags: java, android, arrays, readfile

I have this part of code. I can read all lines from the code. But I want take (read) every letter separately and put it into array. How can I do it? 
For Example: In file are numbers 00010 and I want put it into array like this: array[0,0,0,1,0]

```
public void readTest()
    {
            try
            {
                    InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("test.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String st = "";
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((st=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                            sb.append(st);
                    }

                    br.close();

            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
            }
    }
```

Comment: it'll not be good for array, to have so many letters and index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `br.read()`. It returns the character as integer

```
ArrayList<char> charArray = new ArrayList<>();
int i;
while ((i = br.read()) != -1) {
    char c = (char) i;
    charArray.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()):

> public int read()
>          throws IOException -
>
> Reads a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You should add read every string and add it's letters to array by iterating through it, like this:

```
 while ((st=br.readLine())!=null) {
            sb.append(st);


            for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
                char c = st.charAt(i);        
                yourArray.add(c);
            }
 }
```